# Keep modules enabled/installed?

Tags: 6

I used node_export and UUID to export and then import content from one Drupal 6 site to another.

Do I need to keep these modules enabled for any reason after the import?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On Drupal 6, as per your question, you most likely do NOT need to keep node_export around after your content import/export is done.  It doesn't create any database tables and will only remove config settings variables when you uninstall.

As for UUID it is (depending on  your settings) probably a good idea to keep it around.  It adds/alters some db tables adding its UUID to your content, etc. It would probably be less trouble to keep it rather than remove it and it shouldn't have an impact on the performance of your site.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I did find that leaving UUID enabled is probably best as you suggested.